# Why the images and animation disappear if I add a class to the last column?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to animate 6 images in an infinite loop.

When I add the 6th image and if I add the "poster" class, none of the images are displayed, but if I omit adding the "poster" class to the 6th column (or image), the first 5 images are being displayed and animated correctly.

I don't understand why this happens.

As you can see, the "poster" class is not in the sixth column, so my code works, but as soon as I add that class, it stops working.

(I'm working with bootstrap 5 but I'm sure it has nothing to do with this problem, since the code, as I present it, replicates the problem perfectly)

```css
@keyframes moves {
  to {
    background-position: -100vw 80%;
  }
}

.galeria {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.poster {
  position: absolute;
  animation: moveAcross 6s linear infinite;
}
.poster-1 {
  animation-delay: -0s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-2 {
  animation-delay: -1s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-3 {
  animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-4 {
  animation-delay: -3s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-5 {
  animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-6 {
  animation-delay: -5s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

@keyframes moveAcross {
  0% {
    left: -300px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 110%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="galeria">
        <div class="col poster poster-1">
            <img src="images/posters/poster1.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col poster poster-2 ">
            <img src="images/posters/poster2.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col poster poster-3">
            <img src="images/posters/poster3.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col poster poster-4 ">
            <img src="images/posters/poster4.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col poster poster-5">
            <img src="images/posters/poster5.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col poster-6">
            <img src="images/posters/poster6.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working perfectly with the class `.poster` in the sixth column and with or without Bootstrap 5.

Edit:
You can add one more poster in the end with the visibility hidden and as long as the last poster doesn't contain the class `.poster` it works :)

```
<div style="visibility: hidden;">
    <img src="https://soft.com.mx/test/images/posters/poster6.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
</div>
```

```css
@keyframes moves {
to {
    background-position: -100vw 80%;
}
}

.galería {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.poster {
position: absolute;
animation: moveAcross 6s linear infinite;
}
.poster-1 {
animation-delay: -0s;
animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-2 {
animation-delay: -1s;
animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-3 {
animation-delay: -2s;
animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-4 {
animation-delay: -3s;
animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-5 {
animation-delay: -4s;
animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-6 {
animation-delay: -5s;
animation-duration: 6s;
}

@keyframes moveAcross {
0% {
    left: -300px;
}
100% {
    left: 110%;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="galeria">
        <div class="col poster poster-1">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=1" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col poster poster-2 ">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=2" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col poster poster-3">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=3" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col poster poster-4 ">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=4" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col poster poster-5">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=5" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col poster poster-6">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=6" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you Rakibul.... Here is an example, not working: soft.com.mx/test ... with class added: soft.com.mx/test/index2.html

Comment: It is a typo. In your live website CSS change the selector `.galeria` to `.galería` and it will work perfectly :)

Comment: No, it was a typo here on stackoverflow (already corrected), not in the original code.... please view source on live example. Thanks! ;)

Comment: What I observed is that if you add one more poster and the last poster doesn't contain the class `.poster` it still works.

Comment: You can add one more poster in the end with the visibility hidden and as long as the last poster doesn't contain the class `.poster` it works :)

Comment: Final versión on live site have already 10 posters (not the ones on the examples but clients ones)

Answer (score 0):

Solved...

Just removed *position: relative;* from the *galeria* class and its working perfectly, in fact, rules on this class are not needed.

Final CSS:

```
.poster {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 20vw;
  animation: moveAcross 6s linear infinite;
}
.poster-1 {
  animation-delay: -0s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-2 {
  animation-delay: -1s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-3 {
  animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-4 {
  animation-delay: -3s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-5 {
  animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
.poster-6 {
  animation-delay: -5s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

@keyframes moveAcross {
  0% { left: -30vw; }
  100% { left: 110%; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, those  rules are not necessary but does it really solve the issue? I see the problem is still there with or without this class.

Comment: It was solved, you can see final live versión: https://soft.com.mx/test/index2.html (I will delete that link test soon)

Comment: Yes, it is working. Actually, I had to hard refresh the browser to get the latest version which is working.